Autodesk Forge Viewer: Multiple requests to load the model
We are initializing Model following the documentation.
var options = {
    env: 'AutodeskProduction',
    getAccessToken: getForgeToken,
    api:
      'derivativeV2' +
      (atob(urn.replace('_', '/')).indexOf('emea') > -1 ? '_EU' : ''), // handle BIM 360 US and EU regions
  }

  Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
    viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(
      document.getElementById('forgeViewer'),
    )

However, loading certain models takes a long time, while in BIM 360 it is much faster.
We have noticed that in BIM360 the endpoint to download the model is: https://cdn.derivative.autodesk.com/modeldata/file/urn..., while ours is different (https://cdn.derivative.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/derivatives/urn...)
Additionally, the number of requests is much lower in BIM360.
Could this be the reason why it takes longer, and is there any way to improve the loading time?

BIM360 loads model in svf2 format, so please change your initialization options to the following, and retry to see if it improves.
var options = {
    env: 'AutodeskProduction2',
    api: 'streamingV2'
    getAccessToken: getForgeToken
}

